# Snapping lines to lines in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, line, editing, snapping

How can I move the red line so that it matches the blue line more or less quickly? (See image)

[image]

Comment: You could copy the blue lines which are of interest to the red layer?

Comment: More or less quickly than what? It is not clear what you are trying to do. Do you want to REPLACE any blue line where there is a red line in proximity? If so, there are multiple red lines with some ambiguities- for example how do you want to handle the 2 NE trending red lines where there is only one blue line parallel and nearby. Likewise, there is no blue line remotely similar to the small N-trending red line above the circle. I suggest you take on board the suggestion from @Erik or re-think what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

snap tool from editing toolbox, but probably you need some editing after